# How to pass down item from a flatlist to a grandchild?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a flatlist of items. When I pass the item to the renderItem component everything works perfectly fine. Then when I pass that exact same item to a child within my component responsible for rendering items there are problems.

Normally it works perfectly fine but if there are multiple list items and the one above it gets deleted, it loses proper functionality and becomes very buggy. I think the issue is because an item assumes a previous item's index for whatever reason the grandchild still thinks it is that item rather than it was a different item moving into that index.

My flatlist:

```
<FlatList
            data={this.props.items}
            extraData={this.props.items}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              return (
                <TodoItem
                  todoItem={item}
                />
              );
            }}
          />
```

Then in the TodoItem this is how I pass item to the grandchild:

```
class TodoItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const todoItem = this.props.todoItem;

    return (
        <View>
          <ItemSwipeRow
            item={todoItem}
            completeItem={this.props.deleteTodo}
          >
```

Then in the itemSwipeRow this is how I receive the prop

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Animated, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { RectButton } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';
import { Ionicons, MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { openNotesModal, openDateModal } from '../actions';

const AnimatedIcon = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Ionicons);

class ItemSwipeRow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.item = props.item;
  }

  renderLeftActions = (progress, dragX) => {
    const trans = dragX.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 50, 100, 101],
      outputRange: [-20, 0, 0, 1],
    });
    return (
      <RectButton style={styles.leftAction}>
        <AnimatedIcon
          name='md-checkmark'
          color='#28313b'
          size={45}
          style={[
            styles.actionText,
            {
              transform: [{ translateX: trans }],
            },
          ]}
        />
      </RectButton>
    );
  };

  renderRightAction = (action, name, color, x, progress) => {
    const trans = progress.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [x, 0],
    });
    const pressHandler = () => {
      action(this.item);
    };
    return (
      <Animated.View style={{ flex: 1, transform: [{ translateX: trans }] }}>
        <RectButton
          style={[styles.rightAction, { backgroundColor: color }]}
          onPress={pressHandler}
        >
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name={name}
            size={35}
            color='#28313b'
          />
        </RectButton>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  };

  renderRightActions = progress => (
    <View style={styles.rightSwipeButtons}>
      {this.renderRightAction(
        this.props.openDateModal, 'calendar', '#B8B8F3', 192, progress
      )}
      {this.renderRightAction(
        this.props.openNotesModal, 'pencil', '#F0A202', 128, progress
      )}
      {this.renderRightAction(
        this.props.openDateModal, 'bell', '#db5461', 64, progress
      )}
    </View>
  );

  updateRef = ref => {
    this.currItem = ref;
  };
  close = () => {
    if (this.currItem !== null) { this.currItem.close(); }
  };

  onSwipeableLeftOpen = () => {
    this.props.completeItem();
    this.close();
  }

  onSwipeableRightWillOpen = () => {
    console.log(this.item.text); //tried passing in item here but didn't 
  } //work, instead of console logging on call it did every item @ start
    // then none when it was suppose to log it.
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    const { item } = this.props;
    return (
      <Swipeable
        ref={this.updateRef}
        friction={2}
        leftThreshold={70}
        rightThreshold={40}
        renderLeftActions={this.renderLeftActions}
        renderRightActions={this.renderRightActions}
        onSwipeableLeftOpen={this.onSwipeableLeftOpen}
        onSwipeableRightWillOpen={this.onSwipeableRightWillOpen}
      >
        {children}
      </Swipeable>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  leftAction: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#82ff9e',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  rightAction: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  rightSwipeButtons: {
    width: 192,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  }
});


export default connect(null, { openNotesModal, openDateModal })(ItemSwipeRow);
```

My console logs prove the right item isn't always being rendered. The deleting of the item works properly however if an item is deleted and there is something under it the item that was under it assumes it was the item that was just deleted.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated and I can provide more code if needed.

the code for deleting an item:

```
action that's sent on left swipe–

export const removeTodo = (item) => {
  return {
    type: REMOVE_TODO,
    id: item.id
  };
};

reducer action goes to–

case REMOVE_TODO: {
      const newList = state.todos.filter(item => item.id !== action.id);
      for (let i = 0, newId = 0; i < newList.length; i++, newId++) {
        newList[i].id = newId;
      }
      return {
      ...state,
      todos: newList
      };
    }
```

Comment: Don't you have a natural key in your data? If yes can you use it as key in flatlist?

Comment: each item has an id, are you saying I should make that the index?

Comment: Yes it will better,  like this,  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}

Comment: This may also resolve the problem you are having.

Comment: I applied it. It did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Ok no problem, this is still good to have like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use destructuring assignment to copy the object, rather than refering to the same object:

```
const { todoItem } = this.props
```

further reading: https://medium.com/@junshengpierre/javascript-primitive-values-object-references-361cfc1cbfb0

Comment: So I put that line in the render method and then passed the item to the helper methods. This doesn't work as expected though and is logging the whole list rather than the individual item?

Comment: When I call the method with the state I originally had it only console logs the proper item when it is swiped on (what the helper method is designed to do). When I call it with the deconstruction it logs it right at the render and then nothing when I swipe it.

Comment: Sounds like you are passing a function wrong and mutating state. Please provide the complete 3 components.

Comment: I added the whole itemSwipe component. I don't think the rest of the code makes a difference, but I can add it if you don't think the problem is in the one I added.

Comment: What does the delete to do function look like?

Comment: it's an action. I send it the item and it goes to the redux reducer which checks which id matches that id, then removes it from the state of the list. The delete is working properly for everything except the swipe item. Everything else looks accurate. I will add the code for it though.

Comment: Ok i figured it out. i just called this.props.item before I used it in each helper function and this solved the issue. Thanks so much for your time.